# é aconselhável fazer programas em java apenas criando novas classes dentro de um único projeto no eclipse?

Tags: java

Comecei a estudar a linguagem Java há pouco tempo e estou com uma dúvida,
é melhor criar um novo projeto ou sempre criar uma nova classe dentro de um único projeto mesmo que não seja sobre o assunto relacionado?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

É sempre melhor criar outro projeto.
1º que fica mais organizado.
2º que quando você for compilar e gerar o .jar do projeto para implementação em algum estabelecimento ou algo do tipo, você vai fazer isso só com as classes/arquivos necessários.

Comment: a valeu mesmo Vinicius lino, eu fiquei com essa dúvida porque não achei nada a respeito nos livros e tutoriais, e na hora de procurar os arquivos .jar no meu pc eu não estava achando.

Comment: de nada @MARCELOHENRIQUE, clica na setinha ali pra marcar o comentário como útil kkk